# How to show different menu item based on logged user or logged out user

Tags: wordpress

I want to show different menu items to logged in user and to not logged in user.
Suppose I have menu like below

```
 Home | about us | contact us | Register
```

Now I want to show only three menu after user is logged in which are as below

```
Home | about us | contact us
```

above is just example Is their any facility provided by WordPress by default? or should I do it manually?

Comment: you can use [is_user_logged_in()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.  A simple if statement to see if a user is logged in.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="/account">My Account</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a href="/signup">Sign Up</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay @jeff Sloyer but i want particular item on conditional based so can you please let me know where i put this condition (i mean which file).you tell me file name than it whould be more help full to me.